# Adding value to a props of an object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'd like to push a new state of an array of objects, one of the properties of the object should have the value of the previous object property.

I've tried this code (below) but it says 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'country_id' of undefined"

```
state ={

countryControls: [{

id: null,

country_id: '',
description: '',
city_id: '',
}]
}

addControls () {
var countryControls = this.state.countryControls;
countryControls.push({
id: null,
country_id:countryControls.length > 0 ? 
countryControls[ countryControls.length - 2 ].country_id : '',
description: '',
city_id: '',
});

this.setState({ countryControls: countryControls});
}
```

I expect the output of this will be something like:
first object in the array

> country_id value = 5 (manually input by the user)

second object in the array

> country_id value = 5 ( automatic value from the last input of the user)

Comment: It means `countryControls` have only `1` element.

Comment: hi @MaheerAli, at first yes, but theres an add button that once clicked, it will push another object that will be add to that array... and that new object should have the same prop value to the previous one.

Comment: See I have added the answer. check if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the array length will be `1` then `countryControls[ countryControls.length - 2 ]` will be `undefined`.You should only minus `1`.

```
addControls () {
   var countryControls = this.state.countryControls;
   countryControls.push({
      id: null,
      country_id:countryControls.length > 0 ? 
      countryControls[ countryControls.length - 1 ].country_id : '',
      description: '',
      city_id: '',
});

this.setState({ countryControls: countryControls});
}
```

Comment: @louiekim Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: already did... it says Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.... thanks again